# how to use markdown to create orderlist in github

Tags: github

anyone know how can i create a order number list using markdown on github? for unorder list I can

```
 * aaa
 * bbb
 * ccc
```

then it looks like

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

but i want it looks like

1. aaa
2. bbb
3. ccc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitHub Flavored Markdown specification  for list items](https://github.github.com/gfm/#list-items) does include:

> An **ordered list marker** is a sequence of 1–9 arabic digits (0-9), followed by either a `.` character or a `)` character.
> (The reason for the length limit is that with 10 digits we start seeing integer overflows in some browsers.)

So your markdown source must include those digits explicitly:

```
1. aaa
2. aaa
3. aaa
```

As [flaxel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951752/flaxel) points out, you also have [lazy numbering](https://google.github.io/styleguide/docguide/style.html#use-lazy-numbering-for-long-lists), which means the markdown source would be:

```
1. aaa
1. aaa
1. aaa
```

Comment: You can also use "lazy" numbering. So [Markdown is smart enough to let the resulting HTML render your numbered lists correctly](https://google.github.io/styleguide/docguide/style.html#use-lazy-numbering-for-long-lists).

Comment: @flaxel Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @flaxel. great solution